# How to fix radio that my UV-5R receives signal only when I hold the MONI button even with squelch set from 0 to 9

Tags: uv-5r, reception

My UV-5R stopped receiving signal - that what I thought at first.

After reading many threads here is what I figured out: if I hold the MONI button then I can receive signal

I have 2 UV-5R - exact same model and firmware versions - and I did the following without better results while listening on 162.550 (weather Chanel that I usually listen to) :

- Downloading the firmware from the other one and uploading it in the faulty one.
- Switched the antennas - just to be sure it's not broken
- Changed the squelch and tried every value from 0 to 9 (my default was 5).
- Reset "ALL" the faulty UV-5R

I understand that the MONI button "bypass" the squelch, that said. What should I do to fix the faulty one ? The other one works just fine...

Thanks for helping.

Here is my configuration :

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have tone squelch enabled?

Comment: I don't think so, I added screenshots of my configuration in my original post. Let me know if you need more details. Thanks for your answer

Comment: I think Duston is onto something - but I don'ts see any mention of Tone Squelch in your screenshots. Can you look for that parameter?

Comment: The settings shown are all global settings.  There's no local memory channel settings or even current VFO settings, and tone squelch (TSQL) should be in either of those.  The two settings relevant here are squelch mode (typically set to one of none / T / TSQL) and the tone frequency (one of 51 numbers between 67hz and  254.1hz).  If in TSQL mode and you have the wrong tone, squelch will almost never open.  If set right, it's a great way to not have to hear static when there's nobody talking.  I'd just write a full answer here now, but Duston deserves the honors, or looked for UV5r settings.

Comment: I would confirm the frequency of the nearest WX station, The selelcted one may not be strong enough to break squelch. I would uncheck the TX enable parameter to prevent accidental transmission.

Comment: @Strom: weak signal is not the issue if holding the monitor button allows it to be received and squelch level is already set low enough.

Comment: Hi, I added the other screen shots from CHIRP. To answer the questions from the comments :
- I use CHIRP on OSX to read the UV-5r
- My second uv-5r can clearly receive the weather Chanel without pressing the moni button
- I cloned the faulty uv-5r from the good one and it still does not work without the moni button pressed

Comment: @user10489 In my experience with this radio setting the squelch to 0 is not the same as open squelch.

Comment: @C-Rock This is probably a variation in manufacturing tolerances. Nothing is guaranteed,especially when it comes to Chinese consistency (even from the same factory).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what software you're using, but in CHIRP, the option is on the "Other Settings" tab.  You want to turn off anything CTCSS or DTS related on that menu for that channel.

[image]

Hi thanks for your answer. I don't see differences with your settings - except of the offset that was 0 for m, but event with this offset it does not work. I added the screenshots to my post.

[image]
[image]